# How to override community class in local module

Tags: magento-1.9

Basically there is a method in a core class that I need to override or rewrite. The problem is an existing community method is overwriting this same method and is eventually calling

```
return parent::method();
```

So it is still using its parent's method. How can I create a new class that overrides the PARENT method leaving the existing child alone. What would the php file look like?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to override a community block,model class or method then just copy 
your community file into local for exp:

Like:

> app\code\community\Signifyd\Connect\Block\Renderer.php

just copy it in local codePool

> app\code\local\Signifyd\Connect\Block\Renderer.php

And modify it's function according to your need.

Comment: No I do not want to touch the Community method in this case. I want to change the Parent method that this community is extending. Like stated, the community method is eventually calling the parent I want to change the parent.